# How to run a query and fetch items in 3-dimensional array format

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to get towns from local councils and local councils from states. I was able to get local councils from state, but getting towns from local councils is a problem. It keeps telling me illegal offset. this is my code:

```
$querys = "select id,title from link where (parent is null or parent=0) and title is not null and category='state' and type='1' order by title";
$results = mysql_query($querys,$link) or die(mysql_error());
$counts = 0;
while($rows= mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $state_id[] = $rows["id"];//echo $state_id[$counts]."<br>";
    $state[] = $rows["title"];
    $querylg = "select id,title from link where title is not null and category='lga' and type='1' and parent={$rows['id']} and parent is not null order by title";
    $resultlg = mysql_query($querylg,$link) or die(mysql_error());
    $countlg[$counts] = 0;
    while($rowk=mysql_fetch_array($resultlg,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $lg_id[$counts][] = $rowk["id"];//echo $lg_id[$counts][$countlg]."<br>";
        $lg_name[$counts][] = $rowk["title"];
        $queryt = "select id,title from link where title is not null and category='town' and type='1' and parent={$rowk['id']} and parent is not null order by title";
        $resultt=mysql_query($queryt,$link) or die(mysql_error());
        $counttw[$countlg][$counts] = 0;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultt,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $tw_id[$counts][$countlg][] = $row["id"];
            $tw_name[$counts][$countlg][] = $row["title"];
            $counttw[$countlg][$counts]++;  
        }
        $countlg[$counts]++;
    }
    $counts++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure exactly what you want from your code (ie, how many of the counts, etc, are just there to get your array, and how many are actually required). Could you put the actual output you want?

I would be tempted to rewrite it based on a single joined query:-

```
SELECT a.id AS state_id, a.title AS state_title, b.id AS lg_id, b.title AS lg_title, c.id AS town_id, c.title AS town_title
FROM link a
LEFT OUTER JOIN link b ON a.id = b.parent AND b.title IS NOT NULL AND b.category='lga' AND b.type='1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN link c ON b.id = c.parent AND b.title IS NOT NULL AND b.category='town' AND b.type='1'
WHERE (a.parent IS NULL OR a.parent=0) AND a.title IS NOT NULL AND a.category='state' AND a.type='1' 
ORDER BY a.title, b.title, c.title
```